# How to force update Safari push package?

Tags: safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully integrated Safari push notifications to my website and everything works fine for now. I foresee one problem though, which unfortunately is not covered in Apple Documentation at all: the push package is downloaded only once when a users accepts to receive pushes from my website.

But what if I ever decide to change the iconset, websiteName or the urlFormatString in the website.json file of the push package? Is there any way to force update the old push package **my existing subscribers already have** with a new one?

The only thing [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html) says about changing the contents of the push package is:

> If the contents of your push package ever change, you’ll need to
>   recompute your signature.

But it has nothing to do with force replacing of the old package with a new one.